# About finding $2\times 2$ matrices that are their own inverses

Tags: linear-algebra

They ask me to find all invertible matrices $A$ of the form: $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c&d \end{bmatrix}$ and satisfying $A=A^{-1}$ and $A^t=A^{-1}$. I find that rather complex; does it have anything to do with orthogonality? Not sure. Any help please??

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Given a 2x2 matrix, do you know how to compute its inverse? If not then figure out how to do that. Now that you do, take an arbitrary invertible 2x2 matrix (that is call its entries $a,b,c,d$), compute its inverse and solve the equations $A=A^{-1}$ and $A^t=A^{-1}$.

Comment: Woow! Now I get it! Looks so easy now! thanks!

Comment: you're very welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

Matrices of real entries such that $AA^t=I$ are called unitary matrices and the columns of such matrices must be orthogonal.

and you want to find unitary matrices such that $A^t=A$ which are called symmetric matrices, so the answer will be all symmetric unitary matrices.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll check on those symetric unitary matrices

Comment: @Maximilian1988 My answer classify the answer in words, but if the question was find those A explicitly, try to use what Ittay Weiss wrote.