# Finding all invertible matrices $A$ where $A = A^{-1}$ and $A^{-1} = A^T$

Tags: matrices

Finding all invertible $A$, a $2\times 2$ matrix that satisfies $A = A^{-1}$ and $A^{-1} = A^T$. Hint: The identity $\cos^2t + \sin^2t = 1$ may be useful.

I have no idea how to start this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does $A^{-1}1$ mean? Is it simply $A^{-1}$?

Comment: @julien Yes, it's A to the power of -1 (i.e. the inverse of A) but I didn't know how to type it properly.

Comment: Edited, you simply needed $\{$ and $\}$ around the $-1$.

Comment: Have you checked [Orthogonal Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) ? and [Elementary Construction of Them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Elementary_constructions) ?

Comment: See here this may be useful [link][1]

[1]:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300067/about-finding-2x2-matrices-that-are-their-own-inverses/300070#300070.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  We have:

- $A^T=A$ so the matrix is symmetric. So if $A_{2\times 2}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  a & b  \\
  c & d  \\
   \end{array} \right)$ then $c=b$
- $A^{-1}=A,~~~ A_{2\times 2}$ and if $|A|=ad-bc\neq 0$  so one possibility is $c=0$.
- If $c\neq 0$ , then $b\neq  0$ and we could have $ad-bc=ad-c^2=-1$ and ...