# How do I calculate the circulant determinant $C(1, a, a^2, a^3,\dots , a^{n-1})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The question is pretty straight-forward: how do I calculate the circulant determinant $C(1, a,  a^2, a^3,\dots , a^{n-1})$ ?

Comment: One way to do that is to show it is diagonalizable. Eigenvectors (which are linearly independent) and eignevalues can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300067/about-finding-2x2-matrices-that-are-their-own-inverses

Comment: @julien: I think you wanted another link.

Comment: It seems to be $(1-a^n)^{n-1}$, at least several initial ones follow that pattern.

Comment: @Berci Yes. thanks! It's here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: Please answer your own question, and close the matter.