# Determinant of a general circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, determinant

I'm dealing with a problem that is comparable to "[How do I calculate the circulant determinant $C(1, a, a^2, a^3,\dots , a^{n-1})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300184/how-do-i-calculate-the-circulant-determinant-c1-a-a2-a3-dots-an-1)", yet slightly more difficult: I was asked to determine the determinant of a general circulant matrix, i.e.

\begin{vmatrix} 
a_{1} & a_{2} & ... & a_{n-1} & a_{n} \\
a_{n} & a_{1} & ... & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1} \\
a_{n-1} & a_{n} & ... & a_{n-3} & a_{n-2} \\
\vdots & & & & \vdots \\
a_{2} & a_{3} & ... & a_{n} & a_{1}
\end{vmatrix}

The answer is given, it contains the complex roots of 1, but I do not know how to attain these results.

Comment: You have everything you need [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). Eigenvalues with canonical eigenvectors. Just check that they do what they are supposed to do. Then take the product of the eigenvalues to get the determinant.

Comment: I find it little satisfactory to insert the given expressions in the equations. May there be any way to construct these eigenvalues and -vectors instead? Thanks anyway

Comment: @Francis Ryckaert, yes.  For example, see the post [Circulant matrix : eigenvector](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348134/determinant-of-a-general-circulant-matrix).